# Merge two HashMaps in Rust

Tags: rust

So I'm a bit stuck, trying to merge two HashMaps.

It's easy to do it inline:

```
fn inline() {
    let mut first_context = HashMap::new();
    first_context.insert("Hello", "World");
    let mut second_context = HashMap::new();
    second_context.insert("Hey", "There");

    let mut new_context = HashMap::new();
    for (key, value) in first_context.iter() {
        new_context.insert(*key, *value);
    }
    for (key, value) in second_context.iter() {
        new_context.insert(*key, *value);
    }
    println!("Inline:\t\t{}", new_context);
    println!("Inline:\t\t{}\t{} [Initial Maps Still Usable]", first_context, second_context);
}
```

It's easy enough to make a function:

```
fn abstracted() {
    fn merge<'a>(first_context: &HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>, second_context: &HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>) -> HashMap<&'a str, &'a str> {
        let mut new_context = HashMap::new();
        for (key, value) in first_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        for (key, value) in second_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        new_context
    }

    let mut first_context = HashMap::new();
    first_context.insert("Hello", "World");
    let mut second_context = HashMap::new();
    second_context.insert("Hey", "There");

    println!("Abstracted:\t{}", merge(&first_context, &second_context));
    println!("Abstracted:\t{}\t{} [Initial Maps Still Usable]", first_context, second_context);
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the generic version to work:

```
fn generic() {
    fn merge<'a, K: Hash + Eq, V>(first_context: &HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>, second_context: &HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>) -> HashMap<&'a K, &'a V> {
        let mut new_context = HashMap::new();
        for (key, value) in first_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        for (key, value) in second_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        new_context
    }

    let mut first_context = HashMap::new();
    first_context.insert("Hello", "World");
    let mut second_context = HashMap::new();
    second_context.insert("Hey", "There");

    println!("Generic:\t{}", merge(&first_context, &second_context));
    println!("Generic:\t{}\t{} [Initial Maps Still Usable]", first_context, second_context);
}
```

[The above code on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=411066079819b1db825502934e5b585b&version=stable).

Compiling it:

```
error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str`
```

I get that the compiler is confused about the size of the generic value, but I'm not sure why "str" doesn't have a strict memory size? I know its a String slice and not a type, but still this should work, no? Is this a bug?

I thought this would be a relatively trivial function. If someone has a good solution, I'd love to learn. Actually ideally, I'd love to see a solution with a `trait Mergeable` and write a decorator for HashMap<&K, &V>, such that I can call `let new_context = first_context.merge(&second_context);` but this can be a different question.

Answer (score 72):

A more up to date answer from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ag_dubs/status/731960372157124609):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Mutating one map
fn merge1(map1: &mut HashMap<(), ()>, map2: HashMap<(), ()>) {
    map1.extend(map2);
}

// Without mutation
fn merge2(map1: HashMap<(), ()>, map2: HashMap<(), ()>) -> HashMap<(), ()> {
    map1.into_iter().chain(map2).collect()
}

// If you only have a reference to the map to be merged in
fn merge_from_ref(map: &mut HashMap<(), ()>, map_ref: &HashMap<(), ()>) {
    map.extend(map_ref.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| (k.clone(), v.clone())));
}
```

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac74fd6452396274157ccbfec50643a5&version=stable)

Answer (score 6):

This version does work:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn main() {
    fn merge<K: Hash + Eq + Copy, V: Copy>(first_context: &HashMap<K, V>, second_context: &HashMap<K, V>) -> HashMap<K, V> {
        let mut new_context = HashMap::new();
        for (key, value) in first_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        for (key, value) in second_context.iter() {
            new_context.insert(*key, *value);
        }
        new_context
    }

    let mut first_context = HashMap::new();
    first_context.insert("Hello", "World");
    let mut second_context = HashMap::new();
    second_context.insert("Hey", "There");

    println!("Generic:\t{}", merge(&first_context, &second_context));
    println!("Generic:\t{}\t{} [Initial Maps Still Usable]", first_context, second_context);
}
```

The difference is in the signature of `merge()`. Here is yours:

```
fn merge<'a, K: Hash + Eq, V>(first_context: &HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>, second_context: &HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>) -> HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>
```

Here is mine:

```
fn merge<K: Hash + Eq + Copy, V: Copy>(first_context: &HashMap<K, V>, second_context: &HashMap<K, V>) -> HashMap<K, V>
```

For some reason you are trying to abstract `HashMap<&str, &str>` to `HashMap<&K, &V>`, but this is not really correct: while `&str` *is* a borrowed pointer, it is special - it points to dynamically sized type `str`. Size of `str` is not known to the compiler, so you can use it only through a pointer. Consequently, neither `Hash` nor `Eq` are implemented for `str`, they are implemented for `&str` instead. Hence I've changed `HashMap<&'a K, &'a V>` to `HashMap<K, V>`.

The second problem is that in general you can't write your function if it takes only references to maps. Your non-generic merge function works only because `&str` is a reference and references are implicitly copyable. In general case, however, both keys and values can be non-copyable, and merging them into the single map will require moving these maps into the function. Adding `Copy` bound allows that.

You can also add `Clone` bound instead of `Copy` and use explicit `clone()` call:

```
fn merge<K: Hash + Eq + Clone, V: Clone>(first_context: &HashMap<K, V>, second_context: &HashMap<K, V>) -> HashMap<K, V> {
    // ...
    for (key, value) in first_context.iter() {
        new_context.insert(key.clone(), value.clone());
    }
    // ...
}
```

The most general way, however, is moving maps into the function:

```
fn merge<K: Hash + Eq, V>(first_context: HashMap<K, V>, second_context: HashMap<K, V>) -> HashMap<K, V>  {
    // ...
    for (key, value) in first_context.into_iter() {
        new_context.insert(key, value);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note `into_iter()` method which consumes the map, but returns an iterator of tuples with actual values instead of references.